# A google-maps tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

Should we make a [google-maps](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) tag? It is a map so hence it is on-topic here as it relates to Travel.

The search term `google maps` has 400+ results and is used in quite a lot of q's:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=google+maps+is%3aq

What does everyone think?

Comment: Google maps specifically?  Or online maps?  There are others such as Open Street Map, Apple Maps, Map Quest etc.

Comment: @Midavalo google maps specifically

Comment: Beyond the first page or two of results, most of those questions seem to *mention* google maps rather than actually being about google maps (i.e. people asking about alternatives to google maps, or asking if a route they've found on google maps is reasonable, or asking for something they couldn't find on google maps - none of which would benefit from a google maps tag). I don't have any particularly strong opposition to a google maps tag, but nor do I see much benefit.